# Using substr for one of the database column on Laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use substr for the one of the column in the table. But, it' returning this error: `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::raw does not exist.`

My controller is here:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->q;
        if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

            $estates = \DB::table('estates')
                ->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->get()
                ->raw(substr('address', 1, 4))->get();

            if(count($estates) > 0){
                return view("search", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
            }

        }

        $estates = array();
        return view("search", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");
    }
```

I think this line not quite working? `raw(substr('address', 1, 4))->get();`
Any idea to fix this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: what is "ddre" suppose to be in the query?

Comment: DB::raw('query') is the way to use the raw keyword.You can't run raw() on a Laravel Collection like that. If you want to substring the results you'll be better off just getting all the results, then looping over the $estates and substr the address for each row. DB::raw() is used to write raw sql instead of using the Query Builder

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `->raw()` as a function because it simply doesn't exist. Based on your query, you want to `select` the Substr from the `Address`. In that case, you'd use something like this:

```
$estates = \DB::table('estates')
            ->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orderBy('price')->get()
            ->select(
               'states.*',
               \DB::raw('SUBSTR(`address`, 1, 4) as short_address')
            )->get();
```

And access it like this:

```
$estates->first()->short_address
```

Answer (score 0):

use DB::raw()

```
   $estates = \DB::table('estates')
            ->where("name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
            ->orderBy('price')
            ->select(\DB::raw("SUBSTR('address', 1, 4))")->get();
```

Comment: I tried it but it says: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found`

Comment: add backslash on it. I edit my answer please do check

Comment: yep, tried that too but this time it says: `Illuminate\Support\Collection::select does not exist.`

Comment: sorry, check again,

Comment: If I delete `get` after price this problem occurs: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ddre' in 'field list' (SQL: select ddre from `estates` where `name` LIKE %大阪% or `address` LIKE %大阪% or `company_name` LIKE %大阪% order by `price` asc)`

Comment: >select(\DB::raw("SUBSTR('address', 1, 4))")->get();

Comment: are you sure mate? there is some syntax error in your last update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181717/discussion-between-markantonay-and-kubilay-turgut).